# Insert missing element in a list

Tags: prolog

I have the following list:
`[[1,1,3],[1,2,7],[1,3,9],[2,1,2],[2,2,7],[3,1,4]]`.
I am only interested in the first two components of each elements of the list. To have it right, I know that I am missing a component, for example, `[2,3,2]`. I can determine the max of b in (a,b,c) in the list. I would like to insert the missing element in its right position.

I have started with:

```
work_list([],_,_,_).
work_list([[A,B,_]|F],Alast,Blast,Max):-
A==Alast, work_list(F,A,B,M).
work_list([[A,B,_]|F],Alast,Blast,Max):-
A>Alast, Blast<Max, work_list_miss(F,Alast,Blast,Max).

work_list_miss(F,Alast,Blast,Max):-
   Blast<Max, Blast1 is Blast+1, add_list([Alast,Blast,1],F,FNew). 
work_list_miss(F,Alast,Blast,Max):-
   Blast=Max, Blast1, add_list([Alast,Blast,1],F,FNew), worklist(F,Alast,Blast,Max). 

add_list(A,B,[A|B]).
```

It does not work. Can anyone give a help? When listing it should show: 
`[[1,1,3],[1,2,7],[1,3,9],[2,1,2],[2,2,7],[2,3,1],[3,1,4]]`
Thanks!

Comment: What predicate call do you make and what do you mean "it does not work"?

Comment: you could correct your code removing singletons and undefined calls and retry...

Comment: I mean I do not get the list result I show.

Comment: What is the main predicate you are calling? If it's `add_list`, your predicate only takes the first parameter and makes it the head of a list with the second parameter as the tail and calls it good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs a lot of revision and debugging. Consider instead to use non determinism to obtain the behaviour: here is a predicate inserting an E into a list I, handles the list splitting, and let you to concentrate on the comparisons

```
insert_between(E, I, O) :-
  append(X, [Y,Z|T], I),
  Y =< E, E < Z -> append(X, [Y,E,Z|T], O).
```

Comment: I am a beginner so I still have some problems understanding prolog. What is O doing in the predicate?

Comment: symbols: E for Element, O for Output, I for Input - please forgive my lazyness...

Comment: Sorry, it may seem basic and the X?

Comment: `append/3` can either append two lists, producing their concatentation, but it can also break a list up into a prefix and suffix. Each time the first `append/3` here succeeds, it produces a prefix (`X`), two consecutive list items (`Y` and `Z`) and a suffix `T`, the sum total of which, concatenated together would be the original list `I`. Then, when it finds two consecutive items such that your `E` meets the criteria for fitting in between them, it invokes `append/3` **again**, to construct the result list (`O`) with the element inserted into the proper position.

Comment: Thanks I understand, but I am not able to make it work. Here is a simple version:                work_list_miss([[_,V,A,_,_]|F],Vlast,Alast,Max):- 
 V>Vlast, Alast<Max, Alast1 is Alast+1,
 insert_between([0,Vlast,Alast1,_,_],[[_,V,A,_,_]|F],FNew).